# How to validate total sum through jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this field where the total amount is written and another field below the total amount field which can be appended multiple times by jQuery and the total amount written in field below can't exceed the amount in the total amount field. Is there any way to calculate this?

Form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Total Cost</label>
    <input type="number" name="total_cost" id="total_cost" class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Amount</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="scheduled[1][amount]"  class="form-control txt-schedule-amount" placeholder="Enter Amount">
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: On submit (or whatever other event) just loop over the items and add them up.

Comment: can u be a little more specific i am still a beginner in this..

Comment: Correct the wordings in your question. .use total cost instead of total amount

Comment: Why are you testing that the sum of the amounts "can't exceed" the total amount field? Shouldn't the fields below add up to *exactly* the total amount? Or why not have the total field filled in automatically as the sum of the other fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think you are looking for this.**

```js
function calcSum(obj){
  var tAmmount =0;
  $( ".txt-schedule-amount" ).each(function() {
    tAmmount = tAmmount + valueParse($(this).val());
  });


  var costVal = valueParse($('#total_cost').val());

  if(tAmmount > costVal){
    alert('Your ammount exceed.');
    
  if(obj==false)
    $(".txt-schedule-amount").val(0);
  else
    $(obj).val(0);
  }
}

function valueParse(svalue){
  svalue = parseFloat(svalue);
  if(isNaN(svalue))
    svalue = 0;
  return svalue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Total Cost</label>
    <input type="number" name="total_cost" id="total_cost" class="form-control" onblur="calcSum(false)">
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <label>Amount</label>
    <div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" name="scheduled[1][amount][]"  class="form-control txt-schedule-amount" onblur="calcSum(this)" placeholder="Enter Amount">
      <input type="text" name="scheduled[1][amount][]"  class="form-control txt-schedule-amount" onblur="calcSum(this)" placeholder="Enter Amount">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: will this run on any other version of jquery?

Answer (score 2):

As addition to Optimus answer you can add these lines:

```
$('body').on('keyup','.txt-schedule-amount',function(){
    if(!calculateSum()) return false;
    return true;
})
```

Which will check amounts during editing

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need.On submit call this function

```
 function calculateSum(){
        var sum =0;

        $( ".txt-schedule-amount" ).each(function() {
           sum = sum + parseInt($(this).val());
        });

        $("#total_cost").val(sum);
}
```